# DFA and a Partition of $\Sigma^*$

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata, sets

So I'm learning about Myhill-Nerode relations and as an introduction, the book describes possible partitions for $\Sigma^*$. As an example, given a language $L$, a partition of $\Sigma^*$ would be $\{L, \overline{L}\}$.

Suppose there is a DFA for $L$, the book continues by creating the following notion: For a $q \in Q$ (where $Q$ are the states in the DFA), the set $reach(q)$ is a subset of $\Sigma^*$:

$reach(q) = \{w \in \Sigma^*$ $ |$ $\delta^*(q_s, w) = q\}$

i.e. The set of strings that bring you from the starting state $q_s$ to $q$.

Then it is said that $\{reach(q) $ $|$ $q \in Q\}$ is a partition of $\Sigma^*$ if every state $q$ is reachable from $q_s$ and for every $q \in Q$ and every symbol $a \in \Sigma$, the transition $\delta(q, a)$ is defined.

I don't see how this creates a partition of $\Sigma^*$ and certainly not how to prove this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reminder: a family $S_1, …, S_n$ is a partition of $S$ if and only if it verifies three properties:

- for each $i$, $S_i \neq \emptyset$;
- for $i \neq j$, $S_i\cap S_j = \emptyset$;
- $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nS_i = S$.

I will give you hints for each of those points:

- the first point is proved using the fact that each state $q\in Q$ is reachable from $q_s$;
- the second point is proved using the fact that the automaton is deterministic;
- the third point is proved using the fact that $\delta(q, a)$ is always defined for all $q\in Q$ and $a\in \Sigma$.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I understand the first two hints, those make complete sense to me. I don't however see how to use the third hint to say that the union of all $reach(q)$ would result in $\Sigma^*$. Could you perhaps clarify?

Comment: Given any word $u\in \Sigma^*$, reading it in the automaton will always get you in some state $q\in Q$, because the DFA is [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton#Complete_and_incomplete).

Comment: So what it would mean is that for any word $u \in \Sigma^*$, there is one state $q \in Q$ that is reached (otherwise the second property of a partition for a set would not be satisfied, I think?) and because this holds true for every word $u$ (since the automaton is complete), it hold for $\Sigma^*$?

Comment: Yup, that's more or less it! $\delta^*(q_s, u)$ is always defined, so $u\in reach(\delta^*(q_s, u))$.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the clarification and the help!